# Dealing with old accounts in Gnucash

Tags: gnucash

I have been using Gnucash for a few months for all of my finances. Recently I have started keeping track of various friends owing me money (for instance if I pay for dinner and they say they will pay me back later). Right now I just have a "Who Owes Me" account with a "Misc" sub account. I would like to have a seperate account for each friend but I feel like eventually that would create a lot of clutter with old accounts. For instance, if I create an account for a friend named John and only use it once, I feel like that is a waste. But, deleting an account later on seems like it would be difficult. Does anyone have any advice on how to properly go about this? Should I even worry about having too many stale accounts later on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you got two options:

a) Close the account to Equity

b) You create a class called Closed Accounts or something like this,
   there you can move all the closed accounts.

Which to choose depends if you want to keep the history / reactivate the account (e.g. How long did it take John to pay me back)

If you keep it under a category for closed / dead accounts it will not interfere with you normal usage and you can keep the history

Comment: Awesome thanks! The second option is exactly what I need.